# Remove a line in an HTML file using R grepl

Tags: r, grepl

I have an HTLM document in a object called doc

```
> doc

<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<br>
<p>I am an html file</p>
<script myscript1 src="https://website.com/javascripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
<script myscript2 src="https://website2.com/function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My goal is to create an R function to remove the line with the script myscript1 from doc

```
<script myscript1 src="https://website.com/javascripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
remove <- "<script myscript1 src="https://website.com/javascripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>"
doc <- doc[!grepl(paste(remove), doc),]
```

NB: After removing myscript1, I need to get some elements from the doc thanks to xPath.

Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: What type of object is `doc`? Is it a simple string, or a higher-level object from a scraping package?

Comment: doc is an "externalptr"  object created with XML::htmlParse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to first get a character vector representation of the html file into R and work with that. To do that we can write the externalptr object (blob) out as a text html file and then read it back in with the base function readLines. Consider:

```
old  <- '<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<br>
<p>I am an html file</p>
<script myscript1 src="https://website.com/javascripts.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
<script myscript2 src="https://website2.com/function.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>'

write(old,"old.html")

library(xml2)
doc  <- read_xml("old.html", as_html=TRUE)
write_xml(doc, "foo.html")
bar <- readLines("foo.html")
barbar  <- bar[!grepl("myscript1",bar)]
barbar
#[1] "<!DOCTYPE html>"
#[2] "<html><body>"
#[3] "<h1>Hello</h1>"
#[4] "<br><p>I am an html file</p>"
#[5] "<script myscript2 src=\"https://website2.com/function.js\" 
#    type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"
#[6] "</body></html>"rite(barbar, "new.html")
```

Comment: Thanks rgt47, it works! But I just discovered I can't use xpath anymore (cause xpath can't be applyed to a character type object). Any suggestion?

Comment: one option is to write the character vector out to text file `write(barbar, "new.html")` and then read it back in again `foo  <- read_xml("new.html", as_html=TRUE)`. Seems to work: `xml_find_all(foo, ".")`
`#{xml_nodeset (1)}[1] <html><body>\n<h1>Hello</h1>\n<br><p>I am an html file</p>\n<script myscript2 src="https://website2.com ...`